# How do I evaluate $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{z^{2} d z}{z^{2}+4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How do I evaluate the following integral when where $C$ is the square with vertices at $\pm2, \pm2+4i$,

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{z^{2} d z}{z^{2}+4}$$

#### Using Cauchy integral:

$\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+4}=\frac{z^2}{(z+2i)(z-2i)}=\frac12\frac{z^2}{z+2i}+\frac12\frac{z^2}{z-2i}$ then $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{z^{2} d z}{z^{2}+4} \implies \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac12\frac{z^2 d z}{z+2i}+\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac12\frac{z^2 d z}{z-2i}$

$\frac{z^2}{z+2i}$ is analytic on and inside $C$, hence we can apply Cauchy theorem and for the second term we use Cauchy integral formula,

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac12\frac{z^2 d z}{z+2i}+\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac12\frac{z^2 d z}{z-2i}=0+\frac{1}{4\pi i}2\pi i \times f(2i)=-2$$

#### Using Residue Theorem:

$2i$ is the only isolated singularity in $C$.

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{z^{2} d z}{z^{2}+4}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} 2\pi i \times \text{Res}(f,2i)=i$$

I get correct answer for Residue Theorem but couldn't understand where I do wrong when using  Cauchy integral.

It will be great help if someone clear me when to use which method to find the integral.

Comment: $\lim_{z\rightarrow 2i}(z-2i)\frac{z^2}{z^2+4}=i$ @MartinR

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition is wrong, it should be $\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+4}=\frac12\frac{z}{z+2i}+\frac12\frac{z}{z-2i}$, with $z$ in the numerators on the right, not $z^2$.

Comment: I see. That's why the 1st method give me the wrong answer. Thanks, @MartinR. Could you suggest me, when to use 1st or 2nd method to find answer quickly?

Comment: Use what you feel more comfortable with, the methods are essentially equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't have to use partial fractions but use $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{z+2i}$ for $f(a)$ in the Cauchy Integral Formula, since $f$ is holomorphic in the smallest open disk that fits your $C$.

Then you get $f(2i) = \frac{(2i)^2}{4i} = i$

Comment: problem is that contour contains singularities

Comment: Yeah, but -2i is not in the disk, which contains $C$

Comment: You don't even need a disc around $C$. Just use that $C$ is homotopic to a constant curve, Cauchy's formula holds in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will perform the first computation in a slightly different manner:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{z^2 }{z^2+4}\; dz
&=
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} \frac{(z^2 + 4) - 4}{z^2+4}\; dz
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{C} dz
+
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} (-4)\oint_{C} \frac1{z^2+4}\; dz
\\
&=
0
+
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} (-4)\oint_{C} \frac 1{4i}\left(\frac1{z-2i} - \frac1{z+2i}\right)\; dz
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \cdot i\oint_{C} \frac{dz}{z-2i}
-
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \cdot i\oint_{C} \frac{dz}{z+2i}
\\
&= i-0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How did you evaluate the second last line? @dan_fulea

Comment: Cauchy integral formula (CIF) for the function $f(z)=1$, if we really need CIF, for the first integral. (The function under the integral in the second integral is holomorphic inside $C$.) If the square contour (in contrast to a circle) is the problem, then split the region inside $C$ in three parts, the disc centered in $2i$ and radius $2$, and the four other connected regions remained by cutting it out from the solid square. In these regions the function under the integral is holomorphic. So use integrals on the contours of the four regions and the circle to conclude.